# T-SQL to return only rows where a status category has changed from the previous status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

This seems like it should be easy but I'm tied in knots over this.

My table is similar to this (there are considerably more columns and multiple IDs):

```
EEID (unique)  -  FLSAStatus  -   EffDate
=============     ============    =============
4ABC1        -     A          -    10/01/2010
4ABC1       -      A         -     11/01/2010
4ABC1        -     E          -    11/30/2011
4ABC1       -      O          -    01/01/2012
4ABC1      -       O         -     01/31/2012
4ABC1       -      A          -    11/03/2012
4ABC1       -      A          -    11/13/2012
```

The only record I want to return is the most recent change to FLSA Status - in this case the record from November 3rd, 2012.

My problem is that my query is ignoring the second instance of an "A" status because of my grouping.  I tried pulling the table in as A and B and trying to compare the dates and statuses but I keep getting syntax errors.

For example:

```
SELECT * from 
(
    select a.eeid, a.flsastatus, a.effdate
    from 
        history a with (nolock), 
        history b with (nolock) 
    where
        a.eeid = b.eeid 
    and a.eeid ='4FM7IK0000K0' 
)
Where 
    a.effdate >= b.beffdate 
and a.flsastatus <> b.flsastatus
```

Obviously I'm a beginner - HELP!!  Please!?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the latest change for a given (EEID, FLSAStatus), then you can

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM 
    history A
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT EEID, FLSAStatus, MAX(EffDate) 'MaxEffDate'
        FROM
            history
        GROUP BY EEID, FLSAStatus
    ) AS B
    ON 
        A.EEID = B.EEID AND 
        A.FLSAStatus = B.FLSAStatus AND 
        A.EffDate = B.MaxEffDate
```

But if you are interested in the latest change to a given EEID without worrying about the FLSAStatus, then remove FLSAStatus from the above query.

Comment: The problem is that there are other changes to the records in the table that aren't changes in the FLSA status - those records are coming back as the Max date instead of the one that we want.

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(EffDate)
from history t
where not exists
(select 1 from history where t.FLSAStatus <> FLSAStatus and Effdate > t.Effdate
and t.eeid = eeid)
and t.eeid = 4FM7IK0000K0'
```

Comment: I'm not able to pull back any results with this?

Comment: @user1871450 like in your example i used a specific id in the last line of the code, all you have to do is remove that part of the query. This will work